# When cold water tap on bath is turned hot water tap on sink drips

Tags: bathroom

when cold water tap on bath is turned on water drips from hot water tap on sink and continues when bath tap is closed. we have to turn hot tap on and then off before drip stops.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located? What kind of water supply do you have? How fast is the dripping? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Are you on city water or a well? What kind of plumbing do you have? What kind of faucets (brand & model if you know, pics otherwise) do you have? The more details you can [edit] into your question, the better chance there is of someone getting you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your cold supply pressure controls your hot supply pressure when you turn the bath on you change the pressure in the hot water line in the house.  You likely have a sink valve that is worn out.  When you tighten it the pressure changes cause it to move slightly in it's bore.  If it's a washer type, change the washer otherwise replace the valve.

Comment: Washer less faucets commonly have this issue and replacing the valve is silly when a new cartridge in some models or new springs and O-rings in others may solve the issue.

Comment: Yes that is true unfortunately as I have found there's a huge plethora of these that are on the market and have been sold in the past.  If the tap is a nice steel or brass one and it's a cartridge one then yes, turn off the water, pull the cartridge and o rings take it to a plumbing supply store or a real hardware store and get a replacement.  I personally am partial to the real actual valves myself and I will in fact spend the time taking one apart, then cleaning it, replacing all washers, and lubing it up with plumbing lube in an attempt to save it.  But if it's a plastic valve, chuck it.